# Regular expression to match repeated occurrence of a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a few possible input strings like below:

```
Roll|N/A|300x60|(1x1)|AAA|BBB

Desktop|1x1|(1x1)|AAA|BBB

Desktop|NA|(NA)|AAA|BBB

Roll|N/A|N/A|(1x1)|AAA|BBB
```

from which, I'm trying to detect pattern of type `\d+x\d+` (e.g., '300x60', '1x1' from the first line; '1x1', '1x1' from the second; `None` from the third; and '1x1' from the last). Could someone show me how to write Python regular expression search to capture **none or one or many** occurrence(s) of such pattern in a given string? I tried below already and it only captures either the first or the second occurrence of the pattern in a given sentence. Thank you!

```
r = re.search('(\(?\d+x\d+\)?)+', my_str) 
r.group() # only gives me '320x50' for the first input above
```

Comment: `re.findall(pattern, test_str)` with `r'\(?\d+x\d+\)?'` or `r'\d+x\d+'`

Comment: Just use `re.findall` instead of `re.search` - you should not even need the grouping parenthesis

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thank you! Should I delete this question or leave it?

Comment: @user1330974 that is entirely up to you. If you think this question has no merit any longer you can decide to delete it, but be aware of the possible question ban if you do this too often in too short a time span. (So if this is your first deletion don;t worry about that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
import re
my_strs = ["Roll|N/A|300x60|(1x1)|AAA|BBB", "Desktop|1x1|(1x1)|AAA|BBB", "Desktop|NA|(NA)|AAA|BBB", "Roll|N/A|N/A|(1x1)|AAA|BBB"]
print([re.findall(r'\d+x\d+', s) for s in my_strs])
# => [['300x60', '1x1'], ['1x1', '1x1'], [], ['1x1']]
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/NqCT3A) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT5xC3/1).

The main point is using the [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) that will fetch multiple matches (or captured substrings, but there is no capturing group in the pattern I suggest). The issue you have is that you tried to match *repeated captures* with 1 search operation. Since the substrings are not adjoining, glued, you only had single results.

Comment: Stribizew, thank you. I understood now that I should use `findall`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
import re
input_strings = ['Roll|N/A|300x60|(1x1)|AAA|BBB', 'Desktop|1x1|(1x1)|AAA|BBB',\
                 'Desktop|NA|(NA)|AAA|BBB','Roll|N/A|N/A|(1x1)|AAA|BBB']

print [[ j if j else None for j in [re.findall('(\d+x\d+)', i)]  ][0] for i in input_strings ]
```

Output:

```
[['300x60', '1x1'], ['1x1', '1x1'], None, ['1x1']]
```

Comment: thank you. I accepted Wiktor's answer below because he submitted earlier. Both of your solution works. Thanks again!